# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' React

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, jwt, cryptojs

I installed the **jsonwebtoken** package and ever since I'm getting the following error on running the React app :
[image]

I tried installing the *crypto-browserify* package but that too didn't resolve the issue.

Comment: Is this package more helpful? https://www.npmjs.com/package/crypto

Answer (score 12):

Try adding the following just after the devDependencies in your package.json

```
"devDependencies": {
    ...
},
"browser": {
    "crypto": false
}
```

Comment: This solution works, but would be nice to know why and how :)

Comment: It doesn't work

Comment: No devDependencies in my package.json

Comment: this doesn't help me too i was trying react vite js project

Answer (score 8):

I was facing the same issue. I was trying to generate the keys on in React and was getting the same issue.
Now the issue is resolved.
Just follow the steps given in link
https://github.com/ChainSafe/web3.js#troubleshooting-and-known-issues
Also add these two in package.json

```
"dependencies": {
   "crypto": "npm:crypto-browserify",
   "stream": "npm:stream-browserify",
}
```

Answer (score 7):

If you just want to decode JWTs in React, you can replace `jsonwebtoken` with [`jwt-decode`](https://github.com/auth0/jwt-decode#readme), and then you don't have to worry about installing anything extra or editing `package.json` to resolve the `crypto` error.

`npm i jwt-decode`

```
import jwt_decode from 'jwt-decode'
let decoded = jwt_decode(token)
```

Answer (score 1):

For me installing crypto-browserify worked flawlessly.
You can do this by running the command

```
yarn add crypto-browserify
```

or if you prefer you can install it by doing

```
npm i crypto-browserify
```

This npm will install almost all dependencies of node.js crypto module, check what are available and what are not in case you need more information.

Answer (score 1):

To resolve this issue in the latest React 18.2.0 version.

You first need to install "crypto-browserify".

Use this command to install =>

```
npm install crypto-browserify
```

After the installation go to " webpack.config.js".

You will find this file in the node_modules > react-scripts > config > webpack.config.js.

Inside webpack.config.js

Paste =>

```
const path = require('path');
```

Then search for module.exports and inside module.exports search for resolve: {}
and paste the code like this:-

```
resolve: {
      fallback: {
        crypto: require.resolve('crypto-browserify'),
      },
```

Save the file and run your project.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing `crypto-browserify` package and see if that works. If you still see that error try deleting your node_modules folder and install all packages again.

Comment: It doesn't fix the problem

Answer (score 0):

You can use old vezgo sdk version.

You can install it by doing

npm i vezgo-sdk-js@0.0.6

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33517169)